# Quicken: Add "estimated tax" expense for unrealized gains?

Tags: quicken

Quicken can show in its reports the "unrealized gains" income for investment accounts.  Is there any way to show an estimated "unrealized tax" expense?

For example, if I had $120,000 in `_UnrlzdGain` and a configured 40% marginal tax rate plus 50% exemption (I live in Canada; only 50% of capital gains are taxed), it would add an `_UnrlzdTax` expense of $24,000 when creating reports.

This would be a nice thing just to "keep it real" so I never get too excited about those gains.

Comment: How would quicken know your marginal tax rate?

Comment: You might want to consider forecasting your income monthly on your own, and doing periodic mock-ups of estimated annual T1's to test what your tax amount owing would be. You will need to input the amount and types of income you expect to receive. For example, some stocks you have may make large dividend payouts, which impacts you differently than if you sold them with capital gains tax treatment.

Comment: Yeah, I was just adding that to the question when you commented.  I know it's not perfect but something ball-park would be nice.

Comment: @DStanley, it would have to be configured (perhaps in the report customization).

Comment: @BrianWhite You can leave your question up, but I doubt you'll get anything pre-built that's better than you taking things into your own hands on a monthly basis. Sad truth is that even if such features existed, they probably wouldn't be Canada-centric, so the software might only be able to give you US equivalent numbers.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon, I expect you are correct.  But I'm often pleasantly surprised by what is possible that I don't know or the clever "how about this similar thing" solutions that others come up with.